# What is the probability of flipping at least three heads in a row?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

If you flip a fair coin four times, what is the probability of flipping at least three heads in a row?

It says "three heads in a row". So this makes me think the only possibilities are HHHT, THHH, and HHHH for 3/16. What do we think? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your work is correct.

Comment: You are correct. It'd get more applied if it were at least n heads out of m. Then your method would require more finesse

Answer (score 0):

We need to add all of the probabilities of events that satisfy our criterion.

$$\begin{align}
\text{tot. prob.} &= P(HHHT) + P(THHH) + P(HHHH) \\
&= \frac12 \frac12 \frac12 \frac12 + \frac12 \frac12 \frac12 \frac12 + \frac12 \frac12 \frac12 \frac12 \\
&= \frac{3}{2^4} \\
&=\frac{3}{16} \\
\end{align}$$

So you were spot on! $\ddot\smile$